# How to merge rows in table

Tags: tables

I want to make a table in multiple rows like the following one. Where in my script has problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol,tabularx,capt-of}
\usepackage{multirow}

     \begin{document}

       \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{5cm}{} & \multirow{2}{5cm}{\textbf{Conditions}} \\ 
     \cline{2-3} & \textbf{Frequency} & \multirow{2}{5cm}\textbf{Total}\\ 
    \cline{1-3} 
    & \textbf{VDDA + VDD} & \multirow{2}{3cm}{}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Mode} & \textbf{CLK} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Max} & \textbf{Unit} \\
    \hline
Power Down (TBC) & 0 Hz & 0.6 & 2.00 & $\mu$A \\ \hline
       \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{Current Consumption}
      \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This one is similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188690/21930

Comment: Ah, I see you are not the same who asked that one (I was confused). However… it seems to me that you just copied part of that code without really knowing what you were copying. `\multirow{2}{5cm}{}` and `\multirow{2}{5cm}\textbf{total}` are, for instance, two things that don't make much sense. I think the best you can do (at least at first point) is look the documentation of `multirow` to see how that command works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now work (still using tabularx):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol,tabularx,capt-of}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|p{5cm}|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} & \textbf{Conditions} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Total}} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cline{2-4}
{} & \textbf{Frequency} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{VDDA+VDD}} & {} \\ \cline{1-5}
\textbf{Mode} & \textbf{CLK} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Max} & \textbf{Unit} \\ \hline
Power Down (TBC) & 0 Hz & 0.6 & 2.00 & $\mu$A \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Current Consumption}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `\multirow`? It does exactly nothing, except complicating things.

Comment: True. Though in some cases you may want to have a single cell span an even number of rows with the text centered vertically. In that case the text may be positioned "between" two rows. I don't know it this behaviour can be achieved in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load `multirow` with this slighly modified layout. Instead, the `makecell` package defines a `\thead` command  for cells with a common formatting (say, `\bfseries` here) and you can use `\\` inside theses cells. I also used `booktabs` and suppressed vertical lines for more "professional looking" table.

You don't need it here, but please note that `subfigure` and `subfig` are deprecated now (the former no more maintained) and you should use `subfloat` or `floatrow`.

You should put put your tabulars in a table, not `center`, environment and so use `\caption`. Anyway, if you really had to use `\captionof`, it is defined in the `caption` package.  Also don't load several times the same package.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{multicol,tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}l*{4}{c}@{\,}}
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-4}
& \thead{Conditions \\Frequency}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Total \\ VDDA + VDD}}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Mode} & \thead{CLK} & \thead{Type} & \thead{Max} & \thead{Unit} \\
\midrule
Power Down (TBC) & 0 Hz & 0.6 & 2.00 & \si{\micro\ampere} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Current Consumption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]